# Disable a specific warning in xcode's live-checking only

Tags: xcode, compiler-warnings

XCode's live issue tracking is great, most of the time. But there are a few warnings it complains about that get annoying when I'm still in the middle of writing. For instance, unused variables:

[image: warning]

I know it's unused, I just finished that line and haven't gotten to the code that uses it yet.
I am fairly anal about compiling without warnings (on `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, minus a couple particular ones), so seeing them when I haven't yet had the chance to address them is a bit irritating. However, I do like most of the live-build warnings and once I actually build, I do want to see these.

So, is there any way to disable certain warnings on the live-issue checking only, keeping them on actual builds? I would be willing to use release settings for live-issue and debug for manual builds if that is possible.

A potential workaround I would also accept is delaying the live checking to only run after 10-15 seconds of inactivity.

Comment: I know! And the new Xcode 5 is even worse.. and it slows down Xcode on older machines to wait for these checks.  Like.. in 5 seconds I am going to type a `;`

Comment: how about the `__unused` keyword?

Comment: @holex It would probably be more annoying to have to go back and remove `__unused` from everything once the method is all written.

Comment: you could remove all of them in one session using with Xcode `Find and Repalce in Project...` option, if they are not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Usually i used to do the following to avoid the "unused variable".

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

NSArray *ary = [[NSArray alloc] init];
//your code area

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

So the real time waring for "unused variable" is off on the section. and when i need to enable this i just commented out the "#pragma".

[Reference](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/09/20/disabling-clang-compiler-warnings.html)

Answer (score 0):

using a #pragma to disable the warning will affect live-preview / compilation time... I dont think there is such a way in xcode. :(